# Restrict waking up from suspend to specific buttons only

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, suspend, power-management, lid

I have an Acer Aspire notebook with 16.04 installed on it.

Currently when I suspend, it wakes up on basically everything, including:

- opening the lid
- pressing the <kbd>Power</kbd> button
- pressing any keyboard key
- touching the touchpad

I do not like this behaviour. Ideally I would want my notebook to only wake up when I either press the <kbd>Power</kbd> button or the sleep key combination (<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>). It should stay asleep on all other actions.

Is this possible to configure from Ubuntu, or is that a setting the BIOS/UEFI must provide (which it does not, in my case)? If it's possible, how can I configure it like that?

Comment: Power states like sleep, hibernation, poweroff and whatever else are handled by the BIOS, not the OS.

Comment: But even if it has no control about the initial wakeup, couldn't Ubuntu e.g. cancel the wakeup process and immediately return to sleep if it was not woken up by the power/suspend button?

Comment: Hmm. That might work, but that would be pretty complicated and probably somewhat slow. It might not even be able to detect which key was pressed to wake it up.